# Parse HTML table with jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to develope a Android timetable-app for my courses. Unfortunately my University uses some kind of auto-generated HTML to display the actual timetable. 
Here is the link: http://homepages-fb.th-mittelhessen.de/plaene/stundenplan/Kla1_IES.htm

I need the content ordered like this, for every subject:

```
Monday
14:00 - 20:30
BPS Can
A101
```

My current code looks like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://homepages-fb.th-mittelhessen.de/plaene/stundenplan/Kla1_IES.htm").get();

 for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
     for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
         Elements tds = row.select("td");

         //Times
         if (tds.size() > 6) {
             System.out.println(tds.get(0).text());
         }

     }
 }
```

Output:

```
5-12 13:27:46.211: I/System.out(9779): 1 8:00 9:30
05-12 13:27:46.221: I/System.out(9779): 2 9:45 11:15
05-12 13:27:46.221: I/System.out(9779): 3 11:30 13:00
05-12 13:27:46.221: I/System.out(9779): 4 14:00 15:30
05-12 13:27:46.221: I/System.out(9779): 5 15:40 17:10
05-12 13:27:46.231: I/System.out(9779): 6 17:20 18:50
05-12 13:27:46.231: I/System.out(9779): 7 19:00 20:30
```

Comment: Looks good, you can access specific html elements. Where is the problem? What have you tried and why do you consider yourself stuck with a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution I propose which may not be the solution you may want but here it is. Since it's a table and everything comes one after other, what you can do is, through appropriate Jsoup selectors get the following data one after another.

```
Mo
Do
Mi
Do
Fr
Sa
8:00
9:30
9:45
11:45
Sem Wz
J0122
11:30
13:30
CAE
Wz
J0122
1)
SEM
Wz
J0122
DVI
Eer
J0326
2)
```

...and so on...

Now since you know there are only six working days in a week. You can create a HashMap of String and a LinkedList. String for days of the week and LinkedList for the content which goes in it. In the LinkedList you can first put time and check whether that time has any course following it, then repeat that for all the other timings.

So you now have the data structure that all you need to do is call the day of the week (and the timing if necessary) and get the required course.